# Propagation of Correlated Errors

Tags: mathematical-statistics, error, measurement-error, error-propagation

Suppose I measure three values, a, b, and c. I know independently a+b+c = 1. a, b, and c all have some measurement error; i.e. you could have a = 0.5 +/- 0.1, b = 0.3 +/- 0.05 and c = 0.2 +/- 0.05.

I want to calculate some property f derived from a, b, and c. To estimate the error in f, I propose to take a Monte Carlo approach; i.e. I will perturb a, b, and c within measurement error to get new values (a= 0.4, b= 0.35, c  0.25) consistent with the measurement, then calculate f, and repeat this process N times.

What is the right way to perturb a, b, and c such that I take their measurement errors into account but deal with the fact that they are correlated?

Comment: It depends on the specific distribution of the errors.  What do you know about that?

Comment: Let's say they all follow normal distribution.

Comment: Which one? In other words, exactly what are the correlation coefficients and variances?  These are crucial for the answer.

Comment: The errors I've given are standard deviations, so the variances are just the squares. (0.01, 0.0025, 0.0025). This a simple example of a calculation I'm trying to perform, so I'm not sure what the correlation coefficients will be--in general they will vary. But for this sample problem, lets say they are an order of magnitude less than the variances; -0.00025 for a and b and -0.00025 for a and c. I'm assuming they must be negative due to the closure constraint.

Comment: They cannot be an order of magnitude smaller: because of the sum-to-zero constraint, they should all be close to $-1/3.$  That's why correlation may be an important aspect of the problem.

Comment: Ok, sure, that makes sense. If we suppose that they are -1/3, what would be reasonable method for perturbing the data, such that the perturbed version satisfies a + b + c = 1 and which takes into account their individual errors?